# Map json payload with a new json that have different names of keys

Tags: python, database, postgresql, mapping, payload

```
PAYLOAD = {
    "data": {
        'id': 2,
        'rate_service_id': 4,
        'max_weight': 4.5,
        'max_height': 5,
        'max_length': 6.5,
        'max_depth': 3,
        'fee': 1000

    },
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": "2022-12-15T06:01:49.645358Z",
        "record-type": "data",
        "operation": "insert",
        "partition-key-type": "primary-key",
        "schema-name": "public",
        "table-name": "rates",
        "transaction-id": 124841932694166
    }
}

payload1 = {
    'data': {'length': ,
             "width": ,
             "height": ,
             "weight": 
             },
    'metadata': {
        "timestamp": ,
        "record-type": ,
        "operation": ,
        "partition-key-type": ,
        "schema-name": "",
        "table-name": "",
        "transaction-id": 
    }
}
```

I want to map the keys of PAYLOAD["data] with the keys of payload1["data"] as it have different names.
I want to dynamically store the values of key from PAYLOAD to payload1 where (max_length = length , max_width = depth, max_height = height , max_weight = weight)
same for metadata also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified payload1:

```
payload1 = {
    'data': {"length": "",
             "width": "",
             "height": "",
             "weight":"" 
             },
    'metadata': {
        "timestamp": "",
        "record-type": "",
        "operation": "",
        "partition-key-type": "",
        "schema-name": "",
        "table-name": "",
        "transaction-id": ""
    }
}
```

Then, you can simply use a dictionary to do this task,

```
mapping = {'max_length': 'length',
'max_height': 'height',
'max_depth':'width',
'max_weight': 'weight'}

for key, value in PAYLOAD["data"].items():
    if key in mapping:
        payload1["data"][mapping[key]] = value


mapping = {'timestamp': 'timestamp',
'record-type': 'record-type',
'operation': 'operation',
'partition-key-type': 'partition-key-type',
'schema-name': 'schema-name',
'table-name': 'table-name',
'transaction-id': 'transaction-id'}

for key, value in PAYLOAD["metadata"].items():
    if key in mapping:
        payload1["metadata"][mapping[key]] = value


print(payload1)

# Output:
#{'data': {'length': 6.5, 'width': 3, 'height': 5, 'weight': 4.5},
#  'metadata': {'timestamp': '2022-12-15T06:01:49.645358Z',
#   'record-type': 'data',
#   'operation': 'insert',
#   'partition-key-type': 'primary-key',
#   'schema-name': 'public',
#   'table-name': 'rates',
#   'transaction-id': 124841932694166}}
```